# Set pointer to templated class in class with different template

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to create a class in C++ that can store a pointer to another class. I would also like that the pointer always starts will `nullptr` (preferably not in the constructor).

I have the following example.

```
template <class one>
class BaseA
{
    public:
    ~BaseA(){}

    void computeSomething(){std::cout << "function1 is being called" << std::endl;}
};

template <class two>
class BaseB
{
    public:
    ~BaseB(){}

    template<class one>
    BaseA<one>* myPtr = nullptr;

    template<class one>
    void setPtr(BaseA<one>& obj ){ myPtr = &obj; }
};
```

But upon compilation I am getting the error:

```
 error: data member ‘myPtr’ cannot be a member template
```

An an end result I was hopping to have something like:

```
template<class two> 
void iAmAFunction(BaseB<two>& obj)
{
   obj.myPtr->computeSomething();
}

int main(int argCount, char *args[])
{

    BaseB<int> one;
    BaseA<double> two;

    one.setPtr(two);

    iAmAFunction<int>(banana1);

    std::cout << "End " << std::endl;
 
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show an example of how you want to use these templates.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do ? `myPtr` is a member variable of `BaseB<two>`. As such, it's type must be known at instantiation of said-same. `BaseA<one>* myPtr = nullptr;` is nonsense. You cannot template member vars.

Comment: it is unclear why you use templates in the first place. "I would like to create a class in C++ that can store a pointer to another class" does not require templates.

Comment: I want one templated class (B) to hold a pointer to another templated class A(different templat). Afterwards, I want to use the pointer in object B to do some calculations defined in object A.

Comment: @Bananatrick Show an example or two in code. From your description it is not clear what you really want.

Comment: Ok. I will show the end result

Comment: The type of the pointer `myPtr` being stored within `B` *must* be known at construction of `B`. That doesn't mean you couldn't use a derivative polymorphic design, which would certainly be an option, but you can't latently fabricate a type.

Comment: Also, as a side note: Don't declare destructors if you intend to leave them empty and non-virtual. That has no benefit over using the implicit destructor but may have undesirable side effects.

Comment: With the example you are showing, you probably want to use a non-template base class as shown in the answer that has already been posted and make `computeSomething` a pure virtual function in it which is then overridden by the derived class template. But it is not clear how the template parameter `two` matters at all. This would be the same if `BaseB` was not a template.

Comment: This is to build a solution in another code where both classes are templated, and I need object A in a function where object B is available. As the actual code is substantially bigger, I created this mock problem assert the situation

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to create a class in C++ that can store a pointer to another class. I would also like that the pointer always starts will nullptr

That is:

```
class BaseA {
    public:      
    int a = 2;
};

class BaseB {
    public:
    BaseA* myPtr = nullptr;
    void setPtr(BaseA* obj ){ myPtr = obj; }
};
```

> I want one templated class (B) to hold a pointer to another templated class A(different templat).

There are no pointers to templates. You can store a pointer to an object. And the type of that can be the instantiation of a class template. However, there are no member templates as the errors says. If `BaseA` is a class template then you can introduce a common base for all instantiations of the template and store pointers to that:

```
class Base {};

template <typename T>
class BaseA : Base{
    public:
    int a = 2;
};

class BaseB {
    public:
    Base* myPtr = nullptr;
    void setPtr(Base* obj ){ myPtr = obj; }
};
```

Now `BaseB` can be a class template as well, that does not change anything.

Answer (score -1):

Here is possible solution. Would appreciate other opinions if you have any .

```
class Base {

    void virtual someVirtualFunction(){}
};

template <class one>
class BaseA: public Base
{

    public:
    ~BaseA(){}
    void computeSomething(){std::cout << "function1 is being called" << std::endl;}
    int a = 2;
};

template <class two>
class BaseB
{
    public:
    ~BaseB(){}

    Base* myPtr = nullptr;
    
    void setPtr(Base& obj ){ myPtr = &obj; }
};

template<class two> 
void iAmAFunction(BaseB<two>& obj)
{
   BaseA<double>* check = dynamic_cast<BaseA<double>*>(obj.myPtr);
   if (!check)
   {
       throw std::runtime_error("Not the correct type");
   }

   check->computeSomething();
}


int main(int argCount, char *args[])
{

    BaseB<int> obj1;
    BaseA<double> obj2;

    obj1.setPtr(obj2);

    iAmAFunction<int>(obj1);

    std::cout << "End " << std::endl;
 
}
```

Comment: there are some errors in your code https://godbolt.org/z/KWEa69vdG. Also casting to `BaseA<double>*` will make the function useless for any other `BaseA`, the cast will also fail for the case in your code. DId you mean to dynamic cast to `Base` ?

Comment: General notes: Don't start off an answer with a question. Kinda ruins the tone. Explain what you do, why you do it, and how it solves the asker's problem. When you just show code without explanation, there's an annoying tendency for people to simply copy and use the code and learn nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, Sir. I changed the code, it should work fine now.. . As an explanation: The base class was defined with a virtual function so that I can cast a derived Base in the  `iAmAFunction`. Since I am having problems defining a general procedure (although having a general approach would be far more flexible) and I will later only use one type of template this should work for the time being. Additionally, if the cast is not correct I am throwing an error to stop the program

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).